# In SQL Server 2005, how do I set a column of integers to ensure values are greater than 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, constraints, check-constraints

This is probably a simple answer but I can't find it.  I have a table with a column of integers and I want to ensure that when a row is inserted that the value in this column is greater than zero.  I could do this on the code side but thought it would be best to enforce it on the table.

Thanks!

I was in error with my last comment all is good now.

Comment: Could you clarify the edit a bit?  I would expect the system to raise an exception if you try to write a value that violates the constraint.

Comment: what happened to make the first not work? Can you post the exact constraint code you used and the error or problem you got when you tried to insert data?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use a check constraint on the column.  IIRC the syntax for this looks like:

```
create table foo (
    [...]
   ,Foobar int not null check (Foobar > 0)
    [...]
)
```

As the poster below says (thanks Constantin), you should create the check constraint outside the table definition and give it a meaningful name so it is obvious which column it applies to.

```
alter table foo
  add constraint Foobar_NonNegative
      check (Foobar > 0)
```

You can get out the text of check constraints from the system data dictionary in `sys.check_constraints`:

```
select name
      ,description
  from sys.check_constraints
 where name = 'Foobar_NonNegative'
```

Comment: Will that not just check that it's greater than *or equal to* zero..? Get rid of the equal sign.

Comment: Unnamed constraint may complicate your life later on. Better name your objects from the beginning.

Comment: @Constantin:  would vote up your comment if I could. Sound advice.

Comment: @Constantin, @Mitch Wheat. Ditto - good thinking 99. Post updated to point this out.

Answer (score 6):

Create a database constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT Constraint1 CHECK (YourCol > 0)
```

You can have pretty sophisticated constraints, too, involving multiple columns. For example:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT Constraint2 CHECK (StartDate<EndDate OR EndDate IS NULL)
```

Comment: Don't forget the "NOT NULL". CHECK alone will not reject NULLs. So "EndDate is null" in second example is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `CHECK` constraint when creating your table

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
      [ID] [int]  NOT NULL,
      [MyCol] [int] NOT NULL CHECK (MyCol > 1)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to add a CONSTRAINT to the table field:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName WITH NOCHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT constraintName CHECK (columnName > 0)
```

That optional NOCHECK is used to keep the constraint from being applied to existing rows of data (which could contain invalid data) & to allow the constraint to be added.

Answer (score 0):

you can alter your table and add new constraint like bellow.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
     GO
     ALTER TABLE dbo.table1 ADD CONSTRAINT
        CK_table1_field1 CHECK (field1>0)
     GO
     ALTER TABLE dbo.table1 SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
     GO
COMMIT
```